# multiple mat-select from JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-material, angular6, ngfor

I have an Angular 6 application that chooses a city (that I call in spanish corregimiento), depending of the district  and choose district depending of the province from
[this JSON file](https://github.com/EricLuceroGonzalez/Panama-Political-Division/blob/master/panamaDivision.json).

```
  <!-- ***************SELECT Province *************** -->     
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Provincia" [(ngModel)]="selectedProvince" name='shit' [(value)]="sltdProv">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of datas" [value]="item.distritos" >
        {{ item.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <!-- ***************SELECT District *************** -->
  <mat-form-field *ngIf='selectedProvince'>
    <mat-select placeholder="Distrito" [(ngModel)]="selectedDistr" name='District'>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let distrito of sltdProv" [value]="distrito.corregimientos">
        {{ distrito.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <!-- ***************SELECT City *************** -->
  <mat-form-field *ngIf='selectedDistr && selectedProvince'>
    <mat-select placeholder="Corregimiento" [(ngModel)]="selectedCorr" name='Corr'>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let sub of selectedDistr" [value]="sub.name">
        {{ sub.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In Components file I have:

```
selectedProvince: string;
selectedDistr: string;
selectedDistrict: string;
datas: any;

ngOnInit() {
const Semester = this.getFile.getJSON();
this.http
  .request("../../assets/jsonFolder/panamaData.json")
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.datas = res.json().provincia;
```

This selects the first (and only) value of the JSON in the file. This is an array of 13 JSON objects each one is and province.

**I can make it perfectly on the DOM.** But if I want to save just the name of the province as a variable, it give me the array of JSON objects. And the same for the districts. The **only that is good** is the **city** because is the last one that is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I found some problem in your JSON file. It have Duplicate 'name' variable for

```
id:04 -> id:04-1 -> id:04-1-01
```

item. Could you also add sample plunker link, it will help to debug issue.

Comment: Thanks. let me work on a  minimal working example on that.